# Make/Cmake subdirectory linking to external library fails

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake, linker

I'm currently having trouble in the following setup:

My main project has a subdirector that is a library. This library depends on a system library "triangle" (installed from source). The main project does use a file from the subdirectory.
Cmake of the main project (and the library) work fine.

Building the library works just fine.
(Either in it's own directory or after cmake in the main directory with 
make subdir_lib compiles without problems)

This is where the problems starts.
Building the main project with make project fails. It happens during linking:

```
subdir/libsubdir_lib.a(Test.cpp.o): In function `Test::run()':
/home/mimre/workspace/tmp/cmake-problem/subdir/files/Test.cpp:34: undefined reference to `triangle_context_create'
/home/mimre/workspace/tmp/cmake-problem/subdir/files/Test.cpp:35: undefined reference to `triangle_context_options'
/home/mimre/workspace/tmp/cmake-problem/subdir/files/Test.cpp:42: undefined reference to `triangle_mesh_create'
/home/mimre/workspace/tmp/cmake-problem/subdir/files/Test.cpp:50: undefined reference to `triangle_context_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmake_problem.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'cmake_problem' failed
make[3]: *** [cmake_problem] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmake_problem.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake_problem.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmake_problem.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake_problem.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'cmake_problem' failed
make: *** [cmake_problem] Error 2
```

To avoid having a wall of code in here, I uploaded a minimal example onto github: https://github.com/mimre25/cmake_problem

Also, this is the library I'm using, installed with cmake & sudo make install: https://github.com/wo80/Triangle

I've tried the solutions from various similar threads but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What does your Makefile look like?

Comment: The makefile is generated by cmake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have written this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation for that. Is this a situation where you need to use this Triangle (https://github.com/wo80/Triangle), rather than the original Triangle (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html)? If you can use the latter, I know from experience that its is very easy to link to. I just put it in a subdirectory in my code with this CMakeLists.txt.

```
## This only works for linux. Use an if statement to handle all architectures.
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS
  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O -DLINUX -DTRILIBRARY -w -DANSI_DECLARATORS"
  )

SET(FILES_SOURCE
  triangle.h triangle.c
  )

ADD_LIBRARY( my_local_name_for_triangle_library STATIC ${FILES_SOURCE} )
```

And then I can link to the triangle library I have created like this:

```
include_directories(my_local_triangle_dir)
target_link_libraries(my_local_name_for_triangle_library)
```

However, some of the #define macros are missing in triangle.h, so you need to copy them from triangle.c to triangle.h.

Comment: Unfortunately I run into the same problem. It works all fine when building subdir_lib, but once I'm in the upper most directory, I get `undefined reference to 'triangulate(char*, triangulateio*, triangulateio*, triangulateio*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.. triangle is in a subdirector of subdir (I've update the github repository)

Comment: Oh you should include the library like this: extern "C"{ #include <triangle.h> } if you are using it in C++.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you tried to link a library that doesn't exist (where CMake can find it).

You either need to create a find_library, or when you link to triangle, give a full path with name.

Alternatively, you can leave the source in a sub directory which you can call then link to the name.

Comment: But why does it work when building the sub directory? It also links the library

Comment: In the sub directory you have `add_library(subdir_lib`. That allows the library to be added by the name subdir_lib.

Comment: Yes, I have that: In the subdirectory: add_library(subdir_lib files/Test.cpp files/Test.h)
target_link_libraries(subdir_lib
        triangle), in the main directory add_executable(cmake_problem main.cpp)



target_link_libraries(cmake_problem
        subdir_lib
        triangle)

Comment: Define triangle. You know it as the built file, but CMake doesn't know what it is. If you add the downloaded source as a sub directory, there is an add_library call naming the library "triangle". Short of that, you have to tell CMake where the library is. Either you have to find it, or explicitly say where the built library exists.

Comment: Even if I add `find_package(Triangle REQUIRED)` to both the CMakeLists.txt files it doesn't work. But Cmake does not stop the preocessing, which means it finds the packages..

Comment: I'm not sure how it found it. Are there any variables filled in when it's found?

Comment: Unfortunately not. None of the neither for the following is filled ${TRIANGLE_LIBRARIES}, ${TRIANGLE_LIBRARY}

Comment: These are the set variables after find_package(Triangle REQUIRED): `
-- Triangle_CONFIG=/usr/local/lib/cmake/Triangle/TriangleConfig.cmake
-- Triangle_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS=/usr/local/lib/cmake/Triangle/TriangleConfig.cmake
-- Triangle_CONSIDERED_VERSIONS=1.7.0
-- Triangle_DIR=/usr/local/lib/cmake/Triangle
-- Triangle_FOUND=1
-- Triangle_VERSION=1.7.0
-- Triangle_VERSION_COUNT=3
-- Triangle_VERSION_MAJOR=1
-- Triangle_VERSION_MINOR=7
-- Triangle_VERSION_PATCH=0
-- Triangle_VERSION_TWEAK=0`

Comment: My opinion is that you should take the folder as downloaded and include it in your project as an add_subdirectory, unless you want to mess with the package lookup. I can't say what may be the problem there.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the source directory as sub directory did not work either.

Comment: @Ben "It seems that you tried to link a library that doesn't exist". It doesn't. If the linker cannot find a library it gives an error of the form `cannot find -lfoo`. It does not ignore this fact and proceed to give undefined reference errors to symbols in the missing library.

Comment: That's assuming that CMake told the linker to use the library in the first place. He could verify by building with VERBOSE=1.

Comment: As @MikeKinghan said, I don't get the "cannot find" message:
`subdir/libsubdir_lib.a(Test.cpp.o): In function `Test::run()':
Test.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `triangle_context_create'
Test.cpp:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `triangle_context_options'
Test.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `triangle_mesh_create'
Test.cpp:(.text+0x159): undefined reference to `triangle_context_destroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [cmake_problem] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake_problem.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: My point is that there's a difference between the linker not finding the library and CMake not finding it. CMake has to tell the linker about it in the first place or you won't ever get the `-lfoo` on the command line in the first place. Run `make VERBOSE=1` and see what the linker is told.

Comment: it is linking -ltriangle.
here is a gist with the full output: https://gist.github.com/mimre25/b5f2258a57a4a76c9f5f3693bafc23fd
It seems like include files are missing... I've also updated the cmakelists (see github link in first post)